# Google Assistant

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things, google-assistant-sdk

I try to run the [sample-googleassistant](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant) with android things. I follow all the steps but when I run it, it shows the errors. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: this is a permissions error on your file system. You could try deleting the `build` folder from under the `/app/` directory

Comment: also run the `gradle --stop` command to kill all Gradle processes incase something is keeping a lock on that file. Then try again